# Frasi con pronomi relativi?

Tags: grammar

1. Una cosa che mi sono accorto di aver fatto/che hai fatto.
2. Una cosa che ho paura di fare/che tu faccia.
3. Sono delle persone che non so chi siano.
4. Sono delle persone a cui non so cosa sia passato per la testa
5. Sono dei soldi che bisogna capire come verranno gestiti.
6. C'è gente che non so cosa abbia contro di me.

Io penso siano tutte frasi corrette grammaticalmente, però cercando su google costruzioni frasali simili, mi escono pochi risultati.
Potreste dirmi se sono scorrette o meno?

Answer (score 2):

Sono tutte frasi grammaticalmente corrette, anche se si potrebbero fare alcuni appunti, specie riguardo alla (3).

Sebbene corretta sarebbe meglio utilizzare costruzioni alternative che possano facilitare la comprensione, ad esempio:

> Sono delle persone che non conosco
>
> Sono delle persone che sono a me sconosciute (in questo caso si
>   potrebbe anche omettere *che sono*)

Per darti altri esempi ed esercizi con i pronomi relativi ti segnalo le risorse seguenti:

[Grammatica pronomi relativi (da Treccani)](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-relativi_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)
[Grammatica ed esercizio (da Zanichelli)](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2011/04/28/pronomi-relativi/)
[Esercizi sui pronomi relativi](http://italianoperstranieri.mondadorieducation.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/B1_grammatica_03.pdf)

Comment: La riformulazione più naturale della (3) per me è *Non so che persone siano*. Sono un po' incerto riguardo alla grammaticalità della frase originale, dato il doppio pronome relativo presente (*che/chi*)

Comment: Aggiungo che non se ne trovano molti esempi perché sono frasi "complicate", pur se grammaticalmente corrette. Se la grammatica è "difficile", infatti, l'uso cerca altri modi per dire la stessa cosa.